# How to use nslcd to bind windows AD

Tags: active-directory

I try to use nslcd to auth by LDAP server, if openldap, works fine, but try to WindowsAD, always fail
but the similar config on CentOS is ok, I config the /etc/nslcd, /etc/nsswitch.conf, /etc/pam.d/common-*, after it, if use ldapsearch, it can work with AD server, but use id and getnet, no any id info, same config is works on centos.
I do not want to use sssd/wind to join AD, I just want use AD to auth like openldap. any one success on this nslcd way, pls share the experience
thanks a lot.

Comment: You've not told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using.